# PHP reading data from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a PHP system that has one SQL database (DATABASE1) and inside I have 2 tables (TABLE1 and TABLE2).
There is a list of companies stored in TABLE1 and after you click a desired company you are brought to "info about this company" which is stored in TABLE2. 
Now, at each "info about this company" section/site there is "add info button" which brings up a form, which when filled should store info about the current company opened.

The problem is: How do I echo results for a particular company?
How to tell my code that "this belongs here and should be displayed there"?

For example: company ID in TABLE1 is 21 and info about this company is in TABLE2 with ID 35.
And so it goes on.
But I need this to be DYNAMIC, because I am able to add/remove companies.

Comment: What kind of database is it? MySQL? SQL Server? Pick one.

Comment: It is a mysql database.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any *specific* problem? This is something that any basic PHP/MySQL tutorial covers.

Comment: You know, i am able to echo either ALL "copmany info" (with while) or just the first one. But i need it to be somehow dynamic, but i cant think of a system to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better if you use a foreign key..
The Id of the first table be ' id '. 
Store this id in the second table with some other name like ' c_id '.
Now whatever operation you perform on this data, keep passing the id value by using get method like this

```
$id = $info['id'];  // $info will be a array variable to fetch values of table1
```

For every row of the output add the below anchor tag

```
echo "<a href='update.php?qs=$id'>Add Info</a>";
```

After redirecting to update.php , get the id variable by using

```
$id = $_GET['qs'];
```

Then perform the insert along with this id. Later You can use Joins to fetch the values from both the tables.